# macOS Terminal middle-click accidentally pastes the entire screen buffer

Tags: macos, terminal, copy-paste

I like being able to select text and then immediately middle-click to paste in the Terminal app, especially because its clipboard is separate from the system clipboard. However, sometimes when I middle-click to paste, it will paste what seems to be the entire contents of the screen buffer. In the Terminal preferences, I have the scrollback set to "limit to available memory", so my scrollback buffer often spans days of history.

Am I somehow accidentally selecting the entire buffer when I'm pasting? Is there a way to prevent Terminal from pasting so much data? I don't want to disable middle-click pasting, but whenever this happens, I am forced to close the tab, since the paste doesn't get canceled by Ctl-C.

I am currently using Terminal version 2.10 on macOS Catalina, but I have encountered this issue numerous times on previous versions of Terminal and macOS.

Comment: The usual comment to people who find terminal lacking is to try iterm2  https://iterm2.com. I hsve no idea if it will help in this case

Comment: I'm considering it, but I won't switch yet. I'll wait until I migrate to a new Mac.

Comment: I install iTerm occasionally, look at it, shrug, and remove it again.